# Настройка playbook

Tags: linux, debian, ansible, mikrotik

Возникла проблема при выполнении playbook а точнее на вот этот блок ругается

```
- name: "import"
    action: command ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no {{ ssh_user }}@{{ ssh_ip }} "/import mikrotik_def_confl_{{ name }}.rsc"
    tags: import
    reqister: import_result
```

Ошибка которую выдает терминал:

```
The offending line appears to be:

    tags: import
  - name: "import"
    ^ here
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы зачем-то сдвинули всё после name. Ну и теги тоже не список. Правильно будет так:

```yaml
- name: "import"
  action: command ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no {{ ssh_user }}@{{ ssh_ip }} "/import mikrotik_def_confl_{{ name }}.rsc"
  tags: 
  - import
  reqister: import_result
```

Более того, [для роутерос у ансибла есть модуль](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/routeros_command_module.html) и то что вы хотите можно сделать, описав микротик в виде хоста и выполнив таск

```yaml
  - name: Import config
    routeros_command:
      commands:
      - /import mikrotik_def_confl_{{ name }}.rsc
    tags:
    - import
```

Comment: ок, а срока подключения к самому микротику прописать над модулем routeros_command: ?

Comment: Микротик в хостах надо указать. Ну, как обычный хост

Comment: в хосте прописано подключение 
[mikrotik_ovpn_pki]
test1 ansible_ssh_port=22 ansible_ssh_user=admin ansible_ssh_pass=1234 ansible_ssh_host=192.26.66.66

и не ъочет подключатся после генирации конфига плейбуком. Подскажите что это может быть?

Comment: `mikrotik    ansible_host=10.10.10.10 ansible_user=admin` - этого должно быть достаточно.

Comment: в самом playbook подключение к группе которое прописано в файле hosts реализовывается вот так 
- hosts: mikrotik_ovpn_pki
  serial: 1
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local

????